# grep and replace string spread over several lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, find

I have a string which I want to replace. It is of the format:

```
  VAL1          = "D_AC" ,
  VAL2          = "DRC" ,
  VALX2         = 3.33330000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
```

Note that the string has both double quotes and newline characters.

I want to replace it with another string:

```
  VAL1          = "D_AC" ,
  VAL2          = "DRC" ,
  VALX2         = 2.22110000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
```

Ive tried:

```
export OLD_STRING1="  VAL1          = \"D_AC\" ,"
export OLD_STRING2="  VAL2          = \"DRC\" ,"
export OLD_STRING3="  VALX2         = 3.33330000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, "

export NEW_STRING1="  VAL1          = \"D_AC\" ,"
export NEW_STRING2="  VAL2          = \"DRC\" ,"
export NEW_STRING3="  VALX2         = 2.22110000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, "
```

Then called `grep` and `sed` as so:

```
find . -type f -name '*filename*' -exec sed -i '' s/$OLD_STRING1$OLD_STRING2$OLD_STRING3/$NEW_STRING1$NEW_STRING2$NEW_STRING3/ {} +
```

`sed` generates an error:

```
sed: 1: "s/BX2          = "D_AC ...": unterminated substitute pattern
```

How could I resolve this?

Comment: Consider broadening your solution set to perl.  As I recall, perl had ready support for this sort of thing.

Comment: The first 2 lines in the strings are the same. Are you trying to change `VALX2`, but only after the matches of `VAL1` and `VAL2` ?

Comment: This occurs when the script-string is malformed. This is because you didn't properly quote the script-string. You likely didn't use quotes because you wanted bash to apply variable substitution which could be done by alternating a series of single and double quotes where appropriate. Once this is done and sed does properly execute, this is not to say that it will succeed. Anyway, besides that, I find your question-code contradictory with the question-title, where's the spanning multi-line issue? In this case, you can use sed, perl, or w/e. sed is my go-to for this problem, using `N` to buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a nightmare to try to do robustly and portably with sed since sed doesn't understand literal strings (see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001)).

Given this input where you want to change `file` such that the text contained in `old` becomes the text contained in `new`:

```
$ cat old
  VAL1          = "D_AC" ,
  VAL2          = "DRC" ,
  VALX2         = 3.33330000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
$
$ cat new
  VAL1          = "D_AC" ,
  VAL2          = "DRC" ,
  VALX2         = 2.22110000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
$
$ cat file
foo
  VAL1          = "D_AC" ,
  VAL2          = "DRC" ,
  VALX2         = 3.33330000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
bar
```

and this script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FILENAME==ARGV[1] { old=$0; next }
FILENAME==ARGV[2] { new=$0; next }
s=index($0,old) {
    $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))
}
{ print }
```

it's this simple:

```
$ awk -v RS= -f tst.awk old new file
foo
  VAL1          = "D_AC" ,
  VAL2          = "DRC" ,
  VALX2         = 2.22110000e+04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
bar
```